What happens to "Bridge Bashers"?
In the UK, we have lots of bridges with limited head-room, often where 19th century railway lines pass over roads that were originally intended for horses.
Nowadays, modern large goods vehicles cannot use these routes, but people try, causing a "bridge bash".
The most recent is reported here: Repeatedly bashed railway bridge hit again. There are many online posts, just search for "most bashed bridges".
We rarely hear of the aftermath of these incidents; or, when we do it's only that roads are closed or trains are cancelled.
What happens to the vehicle? Do insurance companies cover the damage?
What happens to the driver? Is there a prosecution or a risk of losing their job?


Are those bridges properly marked as low?

@Trish They sure are! I've added a photo. There are also advance warning signs - it's in everybody's interest to prevent these incidents.

I know of some low passages here too. On one particularly famous one, they even added wooden bars ahead of it, so that you would hit the wood first before you hit the real bridge - people still manage to squeze their vehicles.

I can't quote a law. In Germany, if you have bikes mounted on your roof and drive into a carwash, that's negligent (meaning the insurance pays). As a commercial driver, you are supposed to know how high your lorry is, and there are procedures to follow if it's close, so the same thing becomes gross negligence (insurance pays the victim and asks you for the money back, but doesn't pay your damage).

Can you explain a little what exactly is unclear to you, compared to lets say any other traffic accident? Most of your questions depend on the specific contract in question and either answer would be legally valid if contractually agreed upon previously.

I would guess the question is about if the driver may be held responsible for damage to the bridge, road closures, etc. - the answer to whether the insurance would cover it, is surely "check your contract to see whether it is covered" - that doesn't seem to be a legal question (unless there is some weird jurisdiction where it's illegal for insurance companies to cover it).

In the US, minimum bridge clearance is standardized.  US bridges that are below this standard tend to be subject to frequent crashes (e.g., the "Can Opener" Bridge ).

I only came to link to the Can Opener, as well. Video available here: https://youtube.com/@11foot8plus8?si=1TDMxUe8xTskquwv

We have a tunnel in Paris, next to the Arc de Triomphe that was famous for that (there was even a blog with pictures of accidents). There was at some point a crash every two weeks.

@kaya3 how is the interpretation of a contract not a legal question?

@phoog But there is no reference to an actual contract.

As an example, this driver - in a particular serious case - was given a 12 month suspended sentence + 200 hours of community service: https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-england-kent-42358249

@kaya3 you referred to the contract: "the answer is surely 'check your contract....'"  Then you said "that doesn't seem to be a legal question."  But questions about contracts are legal questions.

@phoog Yes, I meant that the answer is "it depends on the contract", and there is no further legal analysis possible unless a contract is specified. As written, the question is more about what is currently available on the insurance market, than about interpretation of a contract.

@Andy: Myself and bdb484 both mentioned it.  "Can Opener" is one of its nicknames.

Rental truck insurance agreements in North America typically contain a clause excluding “overhead damage” from the coverage.

united-kingdom
The driver may be prosecuted and / or lose their job. In some cases then prosecution can lead to imprisonment or loss of driving licence.
In addition then the driver's employer is liable for the costs of recovering the vehicle, inspection and repair of the bridge, and in the case of railway bridges, delay to train services. The employer may also lose their operators licence, without which they cannot legally use large goods vehicles in their business.
Source (PDF download): Prevention of Bridge Strikes - A Good Practice Guide for Professional Drivers, page 4, section titled "On you and your employer"

Losing their job would not be a direct legal thing.

@MikeB It would be if they were a HGV driver and they lost their HGV licence.

@User65535  No, it wouldn't. Nothing whatsoever in UK law says that an employee that loses their licence must be sacked. The company is perfectly within their rights to continue to employ them, in a non-driving role.

I am surprised at the severity of the consequences / punishments, particularly that they are demonstrably not a deterrent.

@PeterBill or they are a deterrent, but not a 100% effective one

@PeterBill I suspect that the most severe punishments would only occur in the event of a very serious incident (e.g. resulting in serious injury or death), or repeated incidents from the same driver / employer.

Big fines, licence suspension and loss of vehicle registration
new-south-wales
While we don’t have many 19th century bridges still in operation, we do have a lot of 20th and 21st century motorway tunnels where this happens:

The penalties are:


On-the-spot fine for over height trucks entering Sydney tunnels: $4,097

Demerit points for the offence are 12 (of maximum 13 points for a heavy vehicle driver)

Suspension period for a driver’s licence up to six months

Registration suspension period for trucks up to six months.



In addition, the vehicle owner is liable for the damage caused.

I wish we had this in my jurisdiction (US/Maryland). One low overpass in particular gets bashed at least once per year despite warning signs. Neither the company nor the operator are responsible for the repairs and no penalties are ever imposed.

@doneal24 "Neither the company nor the operator are responsible for the repairs and no penalties are ever imposed" How do you know this? Insurance claims aren't public unless there's a dispute and it goes to court. Traffic citations are public, but you have to know the name of the driver to find it, I've never seen a jurisdiction where you can look up by charge or location.

@user71659 I can't speak for doneal24, but over here in the EU, accidents like this are typically notable enough to attract some attention of regional news outlets. Typically, a journalist just sends a few questions to the company operating the vehicle (whose name is typically written in big letters all over the trailer) and/or to the owner of the damaged bridge. And in case the bridge belongs to some public authority (which has to publish all its contracts), you can even find out exactly how much they paid for repairs and where the money came from.

Now I'm wondering what the penalties for hitting the Montague Street Bridge down in Melbourne are

@doneal24 There is a bridge in North Carolina that gets hit so often it has a youtube channel.
https://www.youtube.com/@11foot8plus8

@nick012000 they’re lower than NSW. Incidentally, there’s a YouTuber whose name escapes me, who, while recording a video about how many trucks hit that bridge, had a truck hit the bridge.

As a programmer, it triggers me that the fine is $4097 and not $4096

@pipe As an engineer/programmer it bugs me that you think it should be $4096 and not $4095 /s

This is a partial answer to the portions of the question not answered by others.
Strictly speaking customary insurance policy language and customary insurance company practices in enforcing their rights are not themselves, the law, and neither are common practices for dealing with vehicles damaged in traffic accidents. But, these customs and practices are pervasive, are not too different among common law countries (except New Zealand, which is quite different), and are really necessary to understand to make sense of how the law applies to them. In general, the circumstances involved in the crash and the driver-owner/employee relationship, and the insurance policy are assumed to be typical, but there could always be weird outlier cases.

What happens to the vehicle?


This is a photoshop of a humanized cartoonish lorry, not a real one.
It is usually totaled (assuming a typical worst case scenario crash). It is towed to a scrap yard (at the employer-owner's expense). Then, it goes to lorry heaven. Its metal is crushed and sold for scrap. This makes the lorry very sad. Usually, the lorry's friends can't even attend a funeral for him. The cash from the sale of the scrap will be paid to the employer-owner and may reduce the amount that the employer-owner can get from insurance company.

Do insurance companies cover the damage?

Generally, the insurance company will cover the damage to the vehicle subject to the deductible that the owner of the vehicle loses out of pocket (unless the crash was intentional, such as a road rage or terrorist incident, in which case it isn't covered by insurance).
The insurance company will also cover the employer-owner's liability to third-parties for things like damage to the bridge (without a deductible) up to the policy limits of the insurance policy. The employer-owner has vicarious liability to anyone damages by the accident as a result of the negligence of their driver, and Bridge bashing is almost always negligent (assuming that it isn't intentional).
The insurance company will also usually pay for the lawyers to deal with the situation for the employer-owner. This makes the lawyer look like this:

Disclaimer: Some lawyers have a better attitude and are relentlessly cheerful.
See, e.g., here discussing typical coverages in an insurance policy covering a commercial vehicle in the U.K. (which owners are required by law to have in force).
The insurance company will have a subrogation claim against the driver for negligence for the amount it had to pay on the claim, if the insurance policy doesn't include a "waiver of subrogation" clause. (See generally, e.g., here, discussing insurance subrogation claims in the U.K.). Keep in mind also that the driver is probably not the insured, or at least, not the primary insured typically the insured would be the employer-owner and that would be the part who has suffered the loss and who is most likely to be sued for damage caused to others if the case is not settled by the insurance company.
But the insurance company will only pursue this subrogation claim if the driver has enough collectible assets to justify bringing the lawsuit against the driver.
Often, however, the driver (who is often a novice who only recently joined the work force because experienced drivers rarely make this mistake) has no assets of any value, has lost his job, and has lost his career as a truck driver since his license was revoked, so the driver isn't worth suing.

A typical British bridge basher after the accident.
The insurance rates paid by the employer-owner will probably also go up for a while as well, based upon its claim history.
I am a U.S. based attorney who has represented by insurance companies, and victims of truck hits structure accidents, and have first hand knowledge of that, but as the links above indicate, liability and insurance for accidents causing property damage in the U.K. is quite similar to insurance for accidents in other common law countries including the U.S. which derive their laws on the subject from U.K. law.
The main exception in the common law world is New Zealand which has a comprehensive government run no-fault insurance regime for many kinds harms arising from almost all accidents.

Seriously? Is it necessary to litter SE with memes?

I'm not convinced the first of these claims is true. Since the bridge is often only hit by the towed load, or the very top part of the cab, I would expect that the vehicle would be economic to repair and is unlikely to be written off.

@rexkogitans They should all be collected on the Q&A made for them: The Many Memes of Meta.

@rexkogitans: The joke illustrations would be fine if the answer itself were good, which would just need one thing: sources for its claims.  Without sources, it’s pure information pollution: yet more plausible but totally unsourced claims, giving readers no way to judge if it’s genuine information or pulled straight out of someone’s backside.

@JackAidley I suspect speed is a major factor in what happens to the truck chassis.  At low speed you'll at worst can-open the box like happens at the 11'8" bridge.  That can be replaced for a small fraction of what the truck chassis it's riding on costs; so unlikely to be totaled unless it's already end of life.  At high speeds the shock from impact could deliver enough force to bend the frame; at that point even if the cab is undamaged it's probably more economical to part it out than fully dismantle to move to a new frame.

I agree that losing the memes and jokes would make this a better answer, as would also sources for the practice of insurance companies. Do insurers sue drivers (ever)? When I represented an insurance company we never did this, so it would be nice if you could flesh this out a bit more with evidence.

As others have commented, this answer lacks references, and does not seem country-specific. The 'unhappy lorry' picture is certainly not British.

Presumably the question wears it's Halloween costume this year as a coat of many memes, perhaps some slack is a charitable ward to more tricks or treats.

@FrancisDavey - Insurance companies don't generally need to sue their own customers over accidents. Insurance policies are typically written so that particularly egregious mistakes aren't covered at all (as an exemption for "gross negligence" or similar). Insurers can cap their liability with policy limits, and the driver would be liable for anything beyond that. Whether the bridge owner pursues them for it is another story.

@FrancisDavey "Do insurers sue drivers (ever)?" Keep in mind that the employer-owner and not the driver is the insured.

@PeterBill The "unhappy lorry" picture is an anthropromorphized version of a lorry in the tradition of Thomas the Tank engine. The humor was a natural response to the fundamentally non-legal question of what happens to the vehicle (which is, of course, not a person).

@FrancisDavey Also, keep in mind that most of the time the driver is judgment proof and not sued for that reason.

What I am struggling to get to the bottom of - and the lack of careful analysis does not help this - is whether there would be a subrogation claim against an employee. For there to be subrogation, the employer would have to have a cause of action against their employee (for the insurer to step into), but are there no limits on the ability of an employer to sue their employee for acts done in the course of their employment? I practised extensively in employment for a few years as a young lawyer and do not recall this ever happening. Do you have authorities to throw further light on it?

(The subrogation claim link isn't really relevant to this sort of situation)

@FrancisDavey "are there no limits on the ability of an employer to sue their employee for acts done in the course of their employment?" Correct. It isn't done much because usually employees aren't economic to sue. But, it is done now and then in cases of embezzlement and in big dollar cases against affluent employees. There is no immunity rule (in contrast, employers are usually immune from liability for employee injuries beyond worker's compensation or something similar).

"Employers are usually immune from liability for employee injuries" - citation needed I think.
To focus my question: does an employee owe a duty of care to their employee in this situation, NB: in some form of UK law? Embezzlement would be a direct tort against the employer; whereas failing to notice a road sign leading to indirect liability to their employer is a different tortious situation. I guess what I'm hoping for is some careful; evidenced; discussion somewhere.
